# Monkey тестирование Android приложения

Tags: java, android, test-automation

Подскажите, что обозначают эти проценты? Появляются после начала monkey тестирования.
 Event percentages:
  
0: 15.0%
  
1: 10.0%
  
2: 2.0%
  
3: 15.0%
  
4: -0.0%
  
5: 25.0%
  
6: 15.0%
  
7: 2.0%
  
8: 2.0%
  
9: 1.0%
  
10: 13.0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти проценты показывают процент различных производимых действий (касание, нажатия клавиш и т.п.) от общего количества действий.

Сходу не нашел внятного описания каждого действия в документации, но в [исходниках](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeySourceRandom.java) можно найти такие константы.

```
public static final int FACTOR_TOUCH        = 0;
public static final int FACTOR_MOTION       = 1;
public static final int FACTOR_PINCHZOOM    = 2;
public static final int FACTOR_TRACKBALL    = 3;
public static final int FACTOR_ROTATION     = 4;
public static final int FACTOR_NAV          = 5;
public static final int FACTOR_MAJORNAV     = 6;
public static final int FACTOR_SYSOPS       = 7;
public static final int FACTOR_APPSWITCH    = 8;
public static final int FACTOR_FLIP         = 9;
public static final int FACTOR_ANYTHING     = 10;
```